# How can I get the opcode length of an IR instruction in LLVM

Tags: x86, llvm, llvm-ir, code-size

I need to get the offset and the exact length of opcode corresponding to a particular LLVM IR instruction in x86 architecture. I believe for this I must hack in backends.

I assume there is a way when the opcodes are being generated in x86 backend to dump their offsets and sizes. 
However, considering optimizations and translation of one IR instruction to multiple operations, I'm not sure whether the relation between a single IR instruction and its corresponding opcode is maintainable or not.

My questions are:

- Is this in general possible?
- How to hack the backend to dump the required informations? Is there a generic way to do so, or do I need to hack all backends?

Comment: As you hint, there is not a single relation between an IR instruction and the lowering to the target specific instruction, so you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't assume that a piece of LLVM IR will map into a piece of X86. IR can be recombined+optimized in strange and different ways depending on switches and neighboring code. However, with that proviso said, hopefully this is helpful.

You can write LLVM IR, wrap it in a function and code generate from it. For example, this is a return

```
define void @ lr1() {
    ret void
}
```

You can generate x86_64 instructions from it with the LLVM static compiler, *llc*:

```
llc -march=x86-64 ret.ll
```

It will generate x86_64 instructions which look like:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 11, 0
    .globl  _lr1                            ## -- Begin function lr1
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_lr1:                                   ## @lr1
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
.subsections_via_symbols
```

This will tell you a lot about what is going on with your IR on its journey to X86 machine code. If you're interested in the IR itself and the size of the IR, you need to look at the bitcode it would be serialized to using *opt*:

```
opt ret.ll -o ret.bc
```

bc files are binary LLVM bitcode files which can be interpreted with the LLVM bitcode interpreter, *lli*. They can be disassembled back into IR with `llvm-dis`. To get the bitcode size neither *size* nor *llvm-size* work but you can use *llvm-bcanalyzer*.

```
llvm-bcanalyzer ret.bc
```

If you want to hack, you could [write an LLVM pass](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) but it wouldn't be for the backend (which would make it easier). You can write IR passes or MIR passes.